# Breaking Wifi password knowing its length of 8 [A-Z] alpha (upper-case) characters using Hashcat

Tags: hash, wifi, password-cracking, decryption, wordlist

I got the WPA handshake, now it's turn to crack the password using Hashcat. First, I wanted to make a wordlist of passwords [A-Z] the length of 8, but Crunch (the tool in Kali Linux) said it will take 1TB of storage that I don't have available, so I gave up that way. Is there any way to generate passwords (example: ABCDEFGH) and delete them after its use one by one, during the cracking process?

How long does it take to crack the password with i5-3320M CPU using Hashcat?
Is there any other way you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to generate passwords (example: ABCDEFGH) and delete
>   them after its use one by one, during the cracking process?

Try a mask attack where you've defined the mask as 8 digits of uppercase:

```
hashcat -m 0 -a 3 hashfile ?u?u?u?u?u?u?u?u
```

(replace `-m 0` with whatever mode you're cracking)

There's an excellent tutorial on mask attacks [here](https://www.4armed.com/blog/perform-mask-attack-hashcat/).